# DatePicker android:calendarViewShown

Tags: android, android-widget

I've the following code:

```
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datepicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:calendarViewShown="true" />
```

But the attribute `android:calendarViewShown` is **not** working. Why?
It's in the [Android Developer's Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/).

Answer (score 3):

That's only available for API 11 and higher.  Are you targeting a lower one?